# Recursive parsing with Python's parsec.py library

Tags: python, parsing, parsec, parser-combinators

I have a basic question about parsing using Python's [parsec.py](https://pythonhosted.org/parsec/) library.

I would like to extract the date somewhere inside a text. For e.g,

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. A number 42 is present here. But here is a date 11/05/2017. Can you extract this?
```

or

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
A number 42 is present here.

But here is a date 11/05/2017. Can you extract this?
```

In both cases I want the parser to return `11/05/2017`.

I only want to use `parsec.py` parsing library and I don't want to use regex. `parsec`'s built in regex function is okay.

I tried something like

```
from parsec import *

ss = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. A number 42 is present here. But here is a date 11/05/2017. Can you extract this?"

date_parser = regex(r'[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}')

date = date_parser.parse(ss)
```

I get `ParseError: expected [0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4} at 0:0`

Is there a way to ignore the text until the date_parser pattern has reached? Without erroring?

Comment: Excuse me, but you don't want to "parse the text until the date_parser pattern has reached". You want to **ignore** the text until the date_parser pattern has been reached. If you were parsing the initial text, you would end up with a syntactic analysis of that text. That is the problem parsec is designed for. It is not designed for the problem of finding a regex somewhere inside a long string, which is the problem the regex library is intended to solve. So why do you not want to use it?

Comment: You are right, I want to ignore the text until the pattern has been reached. I will update the question. Secondly, What if I want to parse a specific date from a line which has a certain pattern within it? Also, with more complex logic like this, regex becomes very difficult to maintain.

Comment: `re.findall(r'[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}', ss)` will find all occurrences of your date pattern in `ss`. This is not difficult to maintain, and is simpler than any solution involving parsec.

Comment: @MichaelDyck This logic can become more complicated. What if I want '-' instead of '/' or ':' instead. What if the date structure if Nov 5th 2017. Writing regex with this logic just becomes more complicated and unreadable after sometime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is a parser which skip any unmatched chars, then parse a regex pattern followed.

The date pattern could be defined with `regex` parser,

```py
date_pattern = regex(r'[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}')
```

We first define a parser which consumle an arbitrary char (which would be included in the library (edit: has been included in v3.9)),

```py
def any():
    '''Parse a random character.'''
    @Parser
    def any_parser(text, index=0):
        if index < len(text):
            return Value.success(index + 1, text[index])
        else:
            return Value.failure(index, 'a random char')
    return any_parser
```

To express the idea about "skip any chars and match a pattern", we need to define a recursive parser as

```
date_parser = date_pattern ^ (any() >> date_parser)
```

But it is not a valid python expression, thus we need

```py
@generate
def date_with_prefix():
    matched = yield(any() >> date_parser)
    return matched

date_parser = date_pattern ^ date_with_prefix
```

(Here the combinator `^` means `try_choice`, you could find it in the docs.)

Then it would work as expected:

```py
>>> date_parser.parse("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParseError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
...

ParseError: expected date_with_prefix at 0:27

>>> date_parser.parse("A number 42 is present here.")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParseError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
...

ParseError: expected date_with_prefix at 0:28

>>> date_parser.parse("But here is a date 11/05/2017. Can you extract this?")
'11/05/2017'
```

To avoid the expection on invalid input and returns a `None` instead, you could define it as an `optional` parser:

```py
date_parser = optional(date_pattern ^ date_with_prefix)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. Yes, I was looking for a recursive solution you outlined. Although it works for smaller cases, For larger texts I reach a RecursionError. This is probably a limitation of Python. Not sure if you have more insights into this. But for now, This works. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for let me know the trouble with large text. I think it is solvable and I will comment here when I have some progress on that.